# single page for mobile/iphone and desktop

Tags: iphone, mobile, html

i have developed a mobile version of a page and it uses some mobile specific java and css

i have come across many solutions to point mobile/iphone users to that specific page and desktop users to original webpage.

but what i want is that i get both things in one page and when user is on mobile that certain part of javascript and css run while on same page 
without user being redirected to other pages.

is this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the recent A List Apart article, [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/), useful.  It concentrates mostly on CSS, using media queries to separately target small screen devices, eg.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
    href="shetland.css" />
```

You might also want to have a look at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), it won't help much with detecting a mobile browser specifically, but it does make it easy to do feature detection so you could only load an run particular scripts if certain functionality is available.

Comment: thanks robertc but what i want is some thing for javascript aswell

some thing like this

<!--[if mobile device]>
java script here
<![endif]-->

Comment: You could hang a test off the back of the CSS, style an element a particular way in the main stylesheet (eg. color: red) and another way in the mobile stylesheet (color: blue) then use getComputedStyle to see what colour it is.  If you really want to get into client detection on the server side, have a look at wurfl: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. For CSS just use [media attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) for `link` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="handheld" />
```

For JS you'll have to [detect using user agent signature](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=javascript+how+to+detect+mobile&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=) whether or not visitor is using mobile device.